# Polynomial differentiation map

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, polynomial-rings

I’m studying rings of polynomials
And I don’t understand the following exercise.

“Let F be a field and char(F)=0

Let D : F[x] -> F[x] defined by D(f(x))=f’(x)

Find image of F[x] under D”

The solution says antiderivatives of f’(x) are in F[x], so D is surjective.

But I don’t understand what $\frac{1}{n+1}$$a_ n x^{n+1}$ means.

Is it in F[x]??

I know n$a_n$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n a_n$ but what about $\frac{1}{n+1} a_n$??

When k is an element of a field F, what is $\frac{1}{n} k$ ?

Thank you

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ are also elements of $F$ (presumably) so you can multiply them by $k$ or $a_n$ or any other element of $F$. Thus $\frac{1}{n+1} a_n x^{n+1} \in F[x]$ because $\frac{1}{n+1} a_n \in F$.

Comment: @angryavian  Why is $\frac{1}{n}& an element of F? Is it related to characteristic??

Comment: Since $F$ is of characteristic 0 it contains $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield, hence $\frac{1}{n}\in F$ since $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Umm it doesn’t seem trivial to me. Can I get hints for proof? I didn’t learn it yet

Comment: @ylh0501 $F$ contains the integers (due to the definition of characteristic zero), and the inverses of the integers are fractions like $1/n$.

Comment: I think 1 contained in a field is not the 1 in the integer. Are they same due to the isomorphism from Q to the subfield?